# Can't get list of nested objects in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

i have faced with the problem, that JSON doesn't containe the list of nested objects.

I have 2 classes, one of them is carrying information about auto service, another one containes information about services.

One autoservice can has many services. So, we have the relation - one to many .

`AutoService` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AutoRate")
public class AutoService {

    public AutoService() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "imageURL", nullable = false)
    private String imageURL;

    @Column(name = "mapCoordinate", nullable = false)
    private String mapCoordinate;

    @Column(name = "websiteURL", nullable = false)
    private String websiteURL;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "autoServiceId")
    private List<Service> services;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public String getMapCoordinate() {
        return mapCoordinate;
    }

    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

`Service` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Service")
public class Service {

    public Service() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "serviceId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long serviceId;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private int price;

    @Column(name = "autoServiceId", nullable = false)
    private long autoServiceId;

    public long getId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }


    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public long getAutoServiceId() {
        return autoServiceId;
    }
}
```

Also i am using the `JpaRepository` to get objects from db:

```
public interface AutoRateRepository extends JpaRepository<AutoService, Long> {
}
```

Here is `Controller` class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/directory")
public class ServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private AutoRateService dataBaseService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<AutoService> getData(){
        List<AutoService> dataList = dataBaseService.getAll();
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

But then when i am trying to get JSON object i am getting next:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "serviceName": "SpeedyName",
    "imageURL": "Url for speedy",
    "mapCoordinate": "123123 44121 ",
    "websiteURL": "speedy.com",
    "phoneNumber": "1231251"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "serviceName": "Другой сервис",
    "imageURL": "Урл для второго сервиса",
    "mapCoordinate": "123 12фывфы",
    "websiteURL": "другойсервис.ком",
    "phoneNumber": "12312333"
  }
]
```

There is not lists of nested objects from database ( `List<Services>`

Can you help me to resolve this problem ?

I was told that i had missed the @JsonManagedReference annotation, but it didn't helped me (

Comment: add public List<Service> getServices() {...} method to your AutoService class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the comments, you're missing a `getServices()` method in the `AutoService` entity exposing the collection for serialization.

As a side note, be weary if your `Service` entity has a back reference to the parent `AutoService`.  If it does, you'll need to make sure your JSON framework knows how to handle cyclic loops or you will need to trigger ignoring the back reference when you serialize the `AutoService` instances to avoid a stack overflow.